# TV Show where man could become adult or child

Tags: story-identification, tv

This TV show is old, as I remember it, probably 90's or before. The only thing I can remember is that it involves a man that could become a child... like shape shift. I think they had two actors, one for his 'boy' and one for his 'man' form. That's like all I can remember...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Big John, Little John.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_John,_Little_John)

> The show's main character was a forty-year-old middle school science
> teacher named John Martin (played by Edelman). While vacationing in
> Florida, he drinks from a spring which turns out to be the legendary
> Fountain of Youth sought by Juan Ponce de León. The water changes him
> into a twelve-year-old boy (played by Rist), and back again.
>
> The changes occur spontaneously and without warning.

Comment: Wow, cool. I had thought it was more of a 'superpower' type thing, but this really fits. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to [register your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161). At the moment your account is cookie based and so you could lose access to it in the future.

Comment: I've actually tried to register, but I keep getting an error page. Is there somewhere to ask technical help with this issue?

Comment: @Pete You can ask on [meta]. Tag it with [support] and/or [bug] and include where it happens, what the error is, etc. The usual stuff.